# Finding errors on android source code while debugging

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, adt

(I'm new to android, so not be strog with me)
I am coding with Android Developer Tools Build: v21.0.0-531062. When I debug my code emulator starts normmally, but for example when I click to some botton got an error (Suspended (exception RuntimeException)). I understand that I have somewere error but where, in which line. I don't get such information from the debugger. Where can I find my error. I can do this when my code is small, how can I do this when my code too large?

My error on Debug:

```
Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception RuntimeException))  
    ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 1569    
    ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 1663 
    ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread, ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 117   
    ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(Message) line: 931   
    ActivityThread$H(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 99 
    Looper.loop() line: 123 
    ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 3683    
    Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
    Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 507  
    ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 839  
    ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 597 
    NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]
```

Answer (score 0):

Open the stack trace. The errors are shown in the red lines. The reason for the error is something like,

```
Caused by:
```

The error is caused mostly in the line that has your package name.

Have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11262558/1626878). It provides a very good explanation.

Comment: Excuse me, but I can't find stack trace. Is it View like debug, LogCat, Problems, ...?

Comment: Its logcat. Window->ShowView->Logcat

Comment: Ok, I got it. But there is no error messages. There's only verbose logs, and some warnings

Comment: But my emulator is stops or app not responding. And I get some messages on debug view.

Comment: have you used threads.? first make sure that whether your application has stopped or just the emulator is not responding.